# Use of WAF in a Azure Hybrid Network Topology

Tags: azure

Can we have a Web Application Firewall (WAF) in front of an Azure VPN  gateway in a site-to-site VPN connection between Customer On Premises site and Azure VNet?

Answer (score 0):

WAF is a feature of Azure Application gateway which has OWASP module to prevent from web based attack. Azure VPN gateway is where your tunnel ends and before VPN gateway you will be able to have Application gateway. You can try this scenario:

On-Prem --> VPN gateway --> Application gateway(WAF) -->Web Servers